# in my website the devs come into the other how to solve it [html]

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a template, and i've put the layout but when i come to css and start styling the about section come into the header i don't ;now why!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUJdf.png)

```
  <div class="header">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container">


                  <h1>This is Urban</h1>


                  <p>Aliquam libero augue varius non odio nec faucibus congue
                    felis quisque a diam rutrum tempus massa accumsan faucibus purus.</p>


                  <button>learn more</button>

        </div>
    <div>
  </div>

  <!-- End header -->

  <!-- start about me -->

  <div class="about-me">
    <div class="container">


          <img src="" alt="my-img">
          <h3>Maecenas a gravida quam</h3>


          <button>learn more</button>

    </div>
  </div>


/* start header */

.header {
 background-color: #555;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* end header */

/* start about me */

.about-me{
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

how to solve this problem? it have accured several times with me

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add Clear fix element at the end of the header div .

like this`<div class="header>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div>"`

and you have to add the css like

```
.clearfix{clear:both;}
```

i hope it will work for you or it would be better if you can share html code also

add the div with class clear fix just before the closing tag of header div.

And you can use the same clear fix div at the end of the about me section also to all the sections

Comment: thank you it have worked with me, another thing if you don't mind i've put an overlay on header but it doesn't cover all the header img, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: your welcome and let me see

Comment: i can't add a img in the comment

Comment: do you have the image inside the overlay div ?

Comment: no it's in header div

 
.header {
  background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: so do you want to cover your header section with the image ?

Comment: the image had covered the header, but i've add an overlay on that image, the overlay doesn't cover all the image

Comment: and one more thing your div are not closed properly your overlay div is not closed .   give your headerposition:relative; and add this css to your overlay div{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; } i hope it will work now

Answer (score 0):

you can add Clear fix element at the end of the header div .

like this`<div class="header>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div>"`

and you have to add the css like

```
.clearfix{clear:both;}
```

i hope it will work for you or it would be better if you can share html code also

give your header`position:relative;` and add this css to your overlay div`{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; }`